# With Tom's being a VIP, we should treat him very well

Tags: present-participles, objects

1. With Tom being a VIP, we should treat him very well.
2. With Tom'**s** being a VIP, we should treat him very well.

Do they both sound correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No only the first version but even then I would have written

> Tom being a VIP, we should treat him well

just the use of well means *to a high or satisfactory standard* therefore the very is not required and in fact slightly alters the meaning (see below)

**Personally I would use**

> Tom being a VIP, we should treat him accordingly.

---

**well**; adverb; in a good way, to a high or satisfactory standard: Ref [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/very-well)

**Very well** is used to say that *you agree to do something* or you accept someone's answer, *even though you might not be completely satisfied with it*. Ref [C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/well)

Answer (score -2):

The word "**being**" is archaic.

Nobody has written a sentence in English which used the word "being" anytime in the last 300 years.

Only two types of people use the word "being":

- University professors specializing in one of the social sciences
- lawyers

Examples are as follows:

- "The old man wrote a last will and testament while ***being*** of sound mind and body."
- "A premeent sociologist was written a sequel to her book on gendered spaces and the science of ***being***"

The following are all examples of contemporary English:

- Seeing as Tom is a VIP, we should treat him well.
- Because Tom is a VIP, we should treat him well.
- We should treat Tom Well. He is a VIP.
- **Since Tom is a VIP, we should treat him well**
- Tom is a VIP. We need to treat him well.

The variant I hear people use the most often is shown in **bold** text.

If you want to learn English, then never use the word "being." Don't do it.

Comment: -1, this is absolute nonsense.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/373061/usage-of-being